# Write c# data to weka

Tags: c#, weka

I don't have a clue how can I save data from C# code (more specific: Fourier and wave headers) in an .arff file to use in WEKA? And i need to compare c# data with the data in the weka files.
I don't found much related items on the internet.
Anyone who has a good example?

Comment: What' sthe format of .arff files? Are they plain text, csv, xml?

Comment: Have you seen [Use WEKA with the Microsoft .NET Framework](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+with+the+Microsoft+.NET+Framework)??

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PicNetML](https://github.com/PicNet/PicNetML), a .Net wrapper for the Weka project. There is also a [NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/PicNetML/).

> I don't have a clue how can I save data from C# code

Use the [`SaveToArffFile` method](https://github.com/PicNet/PicNetML/blob/master/PicNetML/Runtime_File_IO.cs)

> And i need to compare c# data with the data in the weka files

Use the [`LoadFromFile` or the `LoadRowsFromFile` method](https://github.com/PicNet/PicNetML/blob/master/PicNetML/RuntimeHelpers/RuntimeFileLoader.cs). (If the filename ends with '.arff' then the `LoadRuntimFromArffFile` will be called). When the file content is loaded you should be able to compare the data.

> Anyone who has a good example?

I don't have any example.

Comment: The example is with .csv files and not arff? I need a good example. How can i compare data from c# with the data in weka and backwards?

Comment: How to include that lib?